# MegaRaid LSI-9271-8i random drive failure

Tags: raid, lsi, megaraid

Anyone have tips on figuring out if I have a bad megaraid card? No matter how I configure with bbu or without. I am using wd red drives and even with brand spanking new drives it marks random drives as failed. While moving data do it. I fear I have a faulty card, but it is brand new as well. So any help in debugging would be great. It's running a home server

Specs:

MB: SUPERMICRO MBD-X10SLM+-F-O uATX Server Motherboard LGA 1150 Intel

OS: Windows 10 Pro workstation on SAMSUNG 840 EVO SAMSUNG 840 EVO 2.5" 120GB

PS:Athena Power AP-U2ATX80FEP8 800W Single 2U IPC Server Power Supply

Mem: 2x Kingston 8GB 240-Pin DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) ECC Unbuffered blades

CPU: Intel Pentium G3258 3.20GHz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks D.Fritz for the tips. Took a bit, but it's the server case. It's a 2u case with on onboard power distribution block for the hd's so the psu(power supply) wasn't directly connected. It was failing to distribute the correct juice and would dip low at times causing things to look like a drive/card issue. Tested it on another server mb and direct connection to psu and and then dumped 4tb's on it without issue. Went back to the original server and set the drives outside the case and direct psu connection raid 50, bbu installed and haven't had a problem. So time to see if I can replace that case power distro or gonna mod the case for direct psu connection.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the BBU if you don't have one.  That can cause problems like what you are describing.

Try a simple RAID 0 on two drives and measure your I/O.  Make sure you are with-in specs of your card. Bad performance is a good indicator of a faulty card.

I've deployed hundreds of these cards across different configurations. Avoid the lowest end versions as I have thrown many of them in the trash.

Comment: Thanks Fitz you got me going in the right direction